# Implementing an interface in Go

Tags: go, interface

My project is organized as follows

```
github.com/achanda/poke
├── cmd
│   └── poke.go
├── scanner.go
├── txt_scanner.go
└── types.go
```

The files are as follows

```
# cat scanner.go
package poke

type Scanner interface {
    Scan() *ScanResult
}

# cat txt_scanner.go
package poke

type txtScanner struct {
    txt string
}

func newTxtScanner(host string) Scanner {
    return txtScanner{txt}
}

func (tcpcs txtScanner) Scan() *ScanResult {
    // do stuff
    return &result
}
```

Now I am trying to call this in my main package (in poke.go) like this

```
package main

import "github.com/achanda/poke"

func main() {
    var sr poke.Scanner
    sr = poke.txtScanner{txt}
    sr.Scan()
}
```

This fails to run with

```
# command-line-arguments
./poke.go:111: cannot refer to unexported name poke.txtScanner
./poke.go:111: undefined: portscan.txtScanner
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you need to access type or field outside package, so you should export them using first letter upper case**:

first you should define your `txtScanner`  and `txt string` with first upper case letter, otherwise you will see this error too:

```
.\poke.go:8: implicit assignment of unexported field 'txt' in poke.TxtScanner literal
```

like this:

```
type TxtScanner struct {
    Txt string
}
```

also see `newTxtScanner(host string)` function in this working sample codes:
poke.go:

```
package main

import "github.com/achanda/poke"

func main() {
    s := "test"
    var sr poke.Scanner
    sr = poke.TxtScanner{s}
    sr.Scan()
}
```

txt_scanner.go:

```
package poke

type TxtScanner struct {
    Txt string
}

func newTxtScanner(host string) Scanner {
    return TxtScanner{host}
}

func (tcpcs TxtScanner) Scan() *ScanResult {
    // do stuff
    result := ScanResult{}
    return &result
}
```

types.go:

```
package poke

type ScanResult struct {
}
```

scanner.go:

```
package poke

type Scanner interface {
    Scan() *ScanResult
}
```